# How delete add space to incorrect combined words in text using regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How I can delete if word in the text combined in incorrect form. For example I have this text:

```
HelloEveryOne, СаломБаХама, Ҳама дарПеши ҷаҳонЯк мебошадАммо.
HELLOeveryOneHelloFORyouYOU HELLO everyOneHello FORyouYOU
canBEcorrectedThisSTRINGinCorrectlyFORm
canBEcorrected ThisSTRINGin CorrectlyFORm
```

```
Hello Every One, Салом Ба Хама, Ҳама дар Пеши ҷаҳон Як мебошад Аммо.
HELLO every One Hello FOR you YOU HELLO every One Hello FOR you YOU
can BE corrected This STRING in Correctly FOR m
can BE corrected This STRING in Correctly FOR m
```

Thanks advance!

Comment: Do all words start with an uppercase letter?

Comment: Yes! For example when word start with uppercase letter and combined with uppercase or lowercase and Uppercase. Example. `ArrayFunction` or  `arrayFunction`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [unicode metacharacters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) to look for uppercase and lowercase letters. Something like:

```
\B(\p{Lu}[\p{Ll}.,!]+)
```

and replace with

```
 \1
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/QskwDd/2/

in PHP it can be used as:

```
$string = 'HelloEveryOne, СаломБаХама, Ҳама дарПеши ҷаҳонЯк мебошадАммо.';
echo preg_replace('/\B(\p{Lu}[\p{Ll}.,!]+)/u', ' \1', $string);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ZjHh4

A simpler approach could be just looking for capital letters and adding a space.

```
\B\p{Lu}
```

replace with:

```
 \0
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QskwDd/1/

Comment: +1 for answering @chris85 but it work a little incorrect for me. For example I've sample entered text: `HElloEveryBody inINCORRECT ORthisTEXT` I must get in that moments so result: `HE llo Every Body in INCORRECT OR this TEXT` in such a case, you need to add where to the right a large letter and on the left a small letter or vice versa. In general, you need to add a space to where the case is changing

Comment: Another example text: `SimPleTEXTor HyperTexTmarkUPlanguAg` How I can get Simple result: `Sim Ple TEXT or Hyper Tex Tmark UP langu Ag` Or is this not possible? @chris85

Comment: @John It is getting a bit more difficult, can you update the question with 5 example strings, the expected results, and define the rules. The original rule was to break after an uppercase letter.

Comment: Yes I can @chris85. Waiting update question! I will inform you about updating the question on the comment.

Comment: There's no real pattern with this new format. You could use 3 expressions and get i done but I cant see it in one.

Comment: @chris85  I got it. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit of tricky challenge to crack! ...but I got it.  Using negative lookarounds proved unfruitful for negating unwanted substrings.  The `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique did the job.

The logic behind it all is to target the three types of words regardless of spacing.  They are:

- Lowercase
- Titlecase
- All Uppercase

See the inline comments in the php code block for layman's pattern explanation.

Pattern: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDvCBC/1)

```
/(?:\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}{2,}+)[,.!?]?(?:\s|$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}{2,}+|\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)[,.!?]?/u
```

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbfc725cdd75fa6d36b37e727f7852ed64f3bb80))

```
$input='HelloEveryOne, СаломБаХама, Ҳама дарПеши ҷаҳонЯк мебошадАммо.
HELLOeveryOneHelloFORyouYOU HELLO everyOneHello FORyouYOU
can,BEcorrectedThisSTRINGinCorrectlyFORm
canBEcorrected ThisSTRINGin CorrectlyFORm.';

//                                optional trailing punctuation-vvvv     vvvv- white space or end of input (that we don't want to replace)
var_export(preg_replace('/(?:\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}{2,}+)[,.!?]?(?:\s|$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:\p{Ll}+|\p{Lu}{2,}+|\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)[,.!?]?/u','$0 ',$input));
//                 all lower-^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^^^-all upper                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-repeat first alternative without trailing white space or end of input
//          one upper then all lower-^^^^^^^^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-discard these matches
```

Output:

```
'Hello Every One, Салом Ба Хама, Ҳама дар Пеши ҷаҳон Як мебошад Аммо.
HELLO every One Hello FOR you YOU HELLO every One Hello FOR you YOU
can, BE corrected This STRING in Correctly FOR m
can BE corrected This STRING in Correctly FOR m.'
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't recognize this locale so I wasn't able to test these strange chars, but the first string can be solved with this:

```
<?php

$str = 'HelloEveryOne';
$newStr = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++ ) {
    $newStr .= ctype_upper($str[$i]) ? ' ' : '';
    $newStr .= $str[$i];
}

echo $newStr;
```

The `ctype_upper` function returns if a string has all chars in uppercase. I'm passing a single char at a time to it, so if it is in uppercase, the program adds a space before the char.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need use for text and not to one word. I must get result with `preg_replace()` @Vinicius Dias

Comment: It works for more than one work @John. You'll just have to set the right locale.